# Making a securestring XML file

Tags: xml, powershell, winscp, securestring

How can I generate a file that looks like

```
<Configuration>
  <UserName>oracle</UserName>
  <Password>01000000d08c9ddf...</Password>
  <SshFingerPrint>01000000d08c9ddf0115d...</SshFingerPrint>
</Configuration>
```

I would like to use the XML file in my script

```
[xml]$config = Get-Content "$PSScriptRoot\config.xml"
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Scp
    HostName = "127.0.0.1"
    UserName = $config.Configuration.UserName
    Password = ConvertTo-SecureString $config.Configuration.Password
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = ConvertTo-SecureString $config.Configuration.SshFingerPrint
}

$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
```

Comment: Adding to what Martin Prikryl gave you. Dealing with securing credentials in PowerShell scripts is a regularly talked about and well covered / documented thing. Be it using xml, txt, registry, DB, or Windows Credential Manager. Nothing prevents you from using them to create the file that you are after. See a sample source list here: --- https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/bv7ywa/whats_the_best_practice_for_passwords_in_ps/epoux2c/?context=3 --- so, there are choices for many use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you took that code from [WinSCP article Protecting credentials used for automation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_protecting_credentials_for_automation).

And that article [shows how to encrypt the password](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_protecting_credentials_for_automation#powershell) for a use in the configuration file:

> To encrypt the password use [`ConvertFrom-SecureString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertfrom-securestring) cmdlet:
>
> ```bsh
> Read-Host -AsSecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString
> ```

*To encrypt a public key you could use the same technique. But it makes no sense. It's **public** key. No need to encrypt it.*